# Need to change ResultSet.getString(Value)---- conditionally

Tags: java

I  have a query and a resultset

I do this

```
while (rs.next())
{    
    String string = rs.getString(ColumnName);

    if (String == "certainvalue")
    {  
        //perform action
    }else {
       //do nothing  
    }
```

My problem is that the if condition doesn't seem to be working.... even though I know "certainvalue" is in the result set, it never evaluates to true, and it never performs the action---- I am confused as to why that is...

is it because i am using a while loop?? or is it because resultsets are just wierd,, ,what is going on???

Answer (score 2):

Java can't compare strings with ==. What you have to do is use the equals method of the String.

```
if (string.equals("certainvalue")) {
    perform action
}
```

Comment: this appears to have nothing to do w/ SQL and resultsets rather how to use JAVA, thanks guys!

Comment: @Max1231 it is good StackOverflow etiquette to accept this question (to give @Tommy reputation points)

Answer (score 0):

String is an object. You can't do a comparison that way (you are trying to compare object reference).

If you are use java(aren't you?) try:

```
String string = rs.getString(columnName);
if (string.compareTo("anotherString") == 0){
}
```

You can use operator == just for primitive types (like int).

Answer (score 0):

It looks you're using Java. In that case, the == operator compares if the two *objects* are the same, not if they represent the same value.

Rewrite the test :

```
if ("certainvalue".equals(string)) { doStuff(); }
```

(You might consider "a".equals(b) to be equivalent to b.equals("a"), but the first form protects you from a NullPointerException if there is no value for the row in the database.)